# Cast NSRange in tests?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, unit-testing

I have a silly issue, I'm just getting started with tests on cocoa and I would like to test a method that returns an `NSArray` with `NSRange` as elements.

`XCTAssert(ranges[0].location == 500, @"Value found is wrong");`

This fails because property location cannot be found on object of type id, but I cannot cast `(NSRange)` either because it's a struct.

My sample array:

`<__NSArrayM 0x600000050680>(
NSRange: {500, 101}
)`

How can I make testing worthwhile for this array?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `NSRange` should be inside an `NSValue` inside the array, so you need to extract the range before you access the `location`.

```
NSValue *value = (NSValue *)ranges[0];
NSRange range = [value rangeValue];

XCTAssert(range.location == 500, @"Value found is wrong");
```

Answer (score 3):

As `NSRange` is not an Objective-C *object*, you cannot store them in an Objective-C collection class, so they need to be wrapped into an `NSValue` object.

See [`[NSValue valueWithRange:]`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/cocoa/reference/foundation/classes/NSValue_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/clm/NSValue/valueWithRange%3a).

Once you've done this, your test becomes:

```
XCTAssert([ranges[0] rangeValue].location == 500, @"Value found is wrong");
```

Or better still, as you get to see both the expected and actual values in the error log:

```
XCTAssertEqual([ranges[0] rangeValue].location, 500, @"Value found is wrong");
```